# Custom forms and Python logic: attribute error

Tags: pyqgis, pyqt

As a beginner to Python, PyQt4, AND QGIS, I am attempting to work with the custom forms feature in QGIS. At this point I'm not sure if my error comes from the code or the .ui. This blog gave me a great head start, but i'm still pretty lost: http://woostuff.wordpress.com/2011/09/05/qgis-tips-custom-feature-forms-with-python-logic/

```
    from PyQt4.QtCore import *
    from PyQt4.QtGui import *

    Naturefield = None
    Diametrefield = None
    myDialog = None

    def formOpen(dialog,layerid,featureid):
        global myDialog
        myDialog = dialog
        global Naturefield, Diametrefield
        Naturefield = dialog.findChild(QLineEdit,"Nature")
        Diametrefield = dialog.findChild(QLineEdit,"Diametre")
        buttonBox = dialog.findChild(QDialogButtonBox,"buttonBox")

 # Disconnect the signal that QGIS has wired up for the dialog to the button box.
        buttonBox.accepted.disconnect(myDialog.accept)

# Wire up our own signals.
        buttonBox.accepted.connect(validate)
        buttonBox.rejected.connect(myDialog.reject)

    def validate():
# Make sure that the Nature field isn't empty.
        if not Naturefield.text().length() > 0:
            msgBox = QMessageBox()
            msgBox.setText("Champ Nature peut pas etre null.")
            msgBox.exec_()
        if not Diametrefield.text().length() > 0:
            msgBox = QMessageBox()
            msgBox.setText("Champ Diametre peut pas etre null.")
            msgBox.exec_()
        else:
    # Return the form as accpeted to QGIS.
            myDialog.accept()
```

However, I'm getting an attribute error and cannot figure out why. Anyone willing to take a look?

```
    if not Nature.text().length()>0:
    AttributeError: 'unicode'object has no attribute 'length'
```

Comment: Is this in qgis 2.0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python's built-in length function looks like this:

```
len(variable)
```

Also, your validate function's logic looks a little off. You're basically set up to run an if statement that does something if Naturefield is blank, then another if Diametrefield is blank, and the else part will only execute if Diametrefield has a value (ignoring whether or not Naturefield does). Maybe that's what you need, just seems off.

Anyway, your two lines that check for some text in Naturefield and Diametrefield should look like this:

```
if not len(Naturefield) > 0:
    do something
```